# Eye Blink detection OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv

I have found some examples in C++ of how to detect **a blink of an eye using OpenCV**.

Unhapilly its pretty hard to find the same for Android.

I have found this:

```
case Sample2NativeCamera.VIEW_MODE_HOUGH_CIRCLES:
        capture.retrieve(mRgba, Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);

         Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 4);

        // doing a gaussian blur prevents getting a lot of small false circles
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGray, mGray, new Size(5, 5), 2, 2);

        // the lower this figure the more spurious circles you get
        // 50 looks good in CANNY, but 100 is better when converting that into Hough circles
        iCannyUpperThreshold = 100;
        Imgproc.HoughCircles(mGray, mIntermediateMat, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2.0, mGray.rows() / 8, 
        iCannyUpperThreshold, iAccumulator, iMinRadius, iMaxRadius);

         if (mIntermediateMat.cols() > 0)
            for (int x = 0; x < Math.min(mIntermediateMat.cols(), 10); x++) 
                {
                double vCircle[] = mIntermediateMat.get(0,x);

                if (vCircle == null)
                    break;

                pt = new Point(Math.round(vCircle[0]), Math.round(vCircle[1]));
                radius = (int)Math.round(vCircle[2]);
                // draw the found circle
                Core.circle(mRgba, pt, radius, colorRed, iLineThickness);

                // draw a cross on the centre of the circle
                DrawCross (mRgba, pt);
                }

            if (bDisplayTitle)
                ShowTitle ("Hough Circles", 1);

        break;
```

But I have no idea on how to use it in my OpenCV sample code. I have all OpenCV sample codes. I am playing with the OpenCV - Face Detection.

I just changed the cascade from Frontal Face to Eyes. **So, it works... it detects the eyes.**

However I need to detect more than just the position of the eyes. **I need to detect when a user blinks an eye.** I saw the code above but I have no idea on how to use it in my OpenCV Face Detection code, since it uses a cascade to detect the eyes. The method above is not using cascades. So, how can I use it?

Any ideas on how can I check the blink of an eye using OpenCV?

I am for almost one week looking for this information in Google and in here but I just can't find one that works with Android. =(

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you can detect the eyes, then you could look for the eyes disappearing then reappearing very quickly.  This would look like a blink.  If you can detect the mouth, then you could make sure it remained in roughly the same place also.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how are your implementation but this code will be helpful to recognize circles, in this case for pupil. You can get a eye roi (region of interest) with Viola Jones, apply the Canny detector and after look for circles (open eye) or line (closed eye) using Hough Transformation.

Some useful links:

Viola Jones: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html

Hough Transform: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Canny detector: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html

Another approach is using Match Template, like http://www.technolabsz.com/2013/05/eye-blink-detection-using-opencv-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Google has released a **FaceDetectorApi()** for Android which gives us the probability of the eye opened for both eyes, using which we can detect eye blinks, here is the project implementation I have done, it works in real time https://github.com/murali129/Eye-blink-detector

Comment: Hi @murali krish, The library you created is accurate and I am using it. But I am facing a challenge that you have used vision api from google which uses cloud calls and it is paid also after some use. Can you please suggest something to me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the blink detection  function in c++ you can use a Native function (JNI) call to the function from android than return a boolean True or false depending the detection to your java code.

Comment: That's exactly what I am asking how to do =)